# Combine 2 maximally correlated discrete distribution method reference

Tags: distributions, correlation

My former colleague left with a method of summing up discrete distributions assuming maximal correlation (comonotonicity). We do not know its reference. Can someone tell what this method is formally called in literature? As an example:

[image]

Comment: What kind of numbers are X and Y? Are they categorical? Are they counts? Something else?

Comment: Real numbers@gung